# Adding negative constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, constraints, anchor

Why do I have to give a negative value to my `rigthAnchor` constraint of `titleLabel` to make a 28 margin from the right side of the view. If I just give it the positive value it goes 28 pixels beyond the view.

```
private func setupLayout() {
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.addSubview(titleLabel)

    // *** imageView ***
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 116).isActive = true
    } else {
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 116).isActive = true
    }
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 224).isActive = true

    // *** titleLabel ***
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -28).isActive = true
    titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 28).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: While not quite explicitly stated in either (very good) answers, I might add it's the **same** for vertical anchors. If you want to anchor the bottom anchor of a view *above* some other view's vertical anchor (top, bottom, even centerY), you need to use a negative value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because according to this

```
titlelbl.right = view.right - 28
```

is same as saying

```
view.right = titlelbl.right + 28
```

> firstItem.anchor = seconfItem.anchor *  multiplier +/- constant

transformed to

```
titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -28).isActive = true
```

**OR**

```
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 28).isActive = true
```

if you don't like negative values

**Edit:**

Meaning of the constraint when it's -28

You'are telling auto-layout to set the max x value of titlelbl to be equal to the max x value of the view minus 28

> | - lbl + 28 - |

but with +28

> | - lbl - | + 28  <<< out of view max x

Comment: is there a better constraint instead of the -28?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has to do with the (X,Y) grid of the window.

You're anchoring your titleLabel's rightAnchor to the view's rightAnchor. However, if' you're constant is 28, your constraining that anchor 28 points along the x-axis, thus moving your label out of the view's frame.

If you're adding these constraints programmatically, you must specify the constant as negative, if you want to move it leftward along the x-axis.